How to attach stringers to outer deck rim joist


I would like to make stairs as seen in the design image. The stringers would attach to the outer joist. But I'm a little perplexed because the outer joist is not secured to the ledger board with a joist connector. How do I properly secure this joist to the ledger board to withstand the weight once the stairs are attached to it?

Something doesn't look right there.  It looks like there's a joist hanger attached to the side of that member, but sideways???  I can't even tell how that outer member is attached to the ledger—if it is at all.  Is it too late to put a hanger on it?  One option may be to simply notch out the deck there til you can access the joist that does have a hanger, where you can attach your stringers.  It'll be a little odd, but hey.
